# Contact IIS via IP from APIM

Tags: azure, iis, azure-api-management

I want to contact a local IIS from Azure API management like (http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/scripts/.....)

I tried to add HOST header to the backend to specify which host I am going to contact but It is not allowed.

Anybody can suggest how to fix this problem.

Comment: Sorry you need to add more information, we're missing some elements here such as where is your iis server hosted ? can you call your endpoint without APIM ? This kind of information will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you can address IP addresses only as IP addresses, i.e. Host header will contain IP address itself. But the ability to modify Host header will be introduced in near future.

Comment: Any suggestion how I can route the incoming connection to a specific application? any workaround

Comment: At the moment you only can provision a proper public DNS record, or put APIM into VNET with your backend and control DNS there (only premium), or have another app on your backend that would accept request sent to IP and route them. All solutions far from ideal, unfortunately.